# kvm network bridge on centos 6

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, linux-networking, bridge

I have a Centos 6 KVM host. I installed the KVM following this manual:

https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/KVM

Its network has been configured as a bridge:

```
[root@server ~]# ifconfig
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6C:3B:E5:B2:EB:6C  
          inet addr:46.165.249.25  Bcast:46.165.249.31  Mask:255.255.255.224
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:254174 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:213352 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:615737501 (587.2 MiB)  TX bytes:16748545 (15.9 MiB)

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6C:3B:E5:B2:EB:6C  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:437599 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:214143 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:631436193 (602.1 MiB)  TX bytes:16829508 (16.0 MiB)
          Memory:f7c00000-f7cfffff 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:5018 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:5018 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1845511 (1.7 MiB)  TX bytes:1845511 (1.7 MiB)

virbr0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:87:43:E3  
          inet addr:192.168.122.1  Bcast:192.168.122.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)

vnet0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr FE:54:00:AA:CB:1E  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1742 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:187 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:500 
          RX bytes:3812 (3.7 KiB)  TX bytes:119656 (116.8 KiB)
```

and routed like:

```
[root@server ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
46.165.249.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.224 U     0      0        0 br0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1009   0        0 br0
0.0.0.0         46.165.249.30   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 br0
```

and ip a

```
[root@server ~]# ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:3b:e5:b2:eb:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:3b:e5:b2:eb:6d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eth2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:3b:e5:b2:eb:6e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: eth3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:3b:e5:b2:eb:6f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
6: virbr0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether 52:54:00:87:43:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
7: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN qlen 500
    link/ether 52:54:00:87:43:e3 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
9: br0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/ether 6c:3b:e5:b2:eb:6c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 46.165.249.25/27 brd 46.165.249.31 scope global br0
12: vnet0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN qlen 500
    link/ether fe:54:00:aa:cb:1e brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

and I created a Ubuntu 14.04 VM and its network is like this:
[image]

but it can't get access to the gateway:
[image]
what is wrong with my configuration!?!?!?

br0 bridge file:

```
#nano /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-br0
DEVICE="br0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
DNS1="37.58.58.137"
DNS2="91.109.25.225"
GATEWAY="46.165.249.30"
HOSTNAME="localhost.localdomain"
IPADDR="46.165.249.25"
IPV6INIT="no"
MTU="1500"
NETMASK="255.255.255.224"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Bridge"
DELAY=0
```

eth0 file:

```
#nano /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0 
DEVICE="eth0"
BOOTPROTO="static"
DNS1="37.58.58.137"
DNS2="91.109.25.225"
GATEWAY="46.165.249.30"
HOSTNAME="localhost.localdomain"
HWADDR="6C:3B:E5:B2:EB:6C"
IPADDR="46.165.249.25"
IPV6INIT="no"
MTU="1500"
NETMASK="255.255.255.224"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="yes"
TYPE="Ethernet"
UUID="1c33f9f6-36ae-45c7-82a1-1bd3bb8d2d32"
BOOTPROTO="none"
BRIDGE=br0
```

eth1 file:

```
#nano /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth1 
DEVICE="eth1"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
DHCP_HOSTNAME="localhost.localdomain"
HWADDR="6C:3B:E5:B2:EB:6D"
NM_CONTROLLED="yes"
ONBOOT="no"
TYPE="Ethernet"
UUID="646064b0-b8e7-4476-82fc-01026c0c962f"
```

UPDATE:
server information:

```
ip:46.165.249.25
netmask:255.255.255.224
gateway:46.165.249.30
```

guest information:

```
ip:91.109.28.231
netmask:255.255.255.240
gateway:91.109.28.254
```

i installed openvz with these ips and every thing goes well.

guest xml interface:

```
<interface type='bridge'>
  <mac address='52:54:00:aa:cb:1e'/>
  <source bridge='br0'/>
  <target dev='vnet0'/>
  <model type='virtio'/>
  <alias name='net0'/>
  <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
</interface>
```

brctl show:

```
[root@server ~]# brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.6c3be5b2eb6c       no              eth0
                                                        vnet0
virbr0          8000.5254008743e3       yes             virbr0-nic
```

Comment: How did you configure networking in the guest?

Comment: @MichaelHampton thank you for answer. images from guest hase been uploaded.

Comment: You've tried to route to the wrong IP address. Contact your service provider to get the correct information.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i asked provider regarding this problem and thay said ips are right!! can you tell me which ip is not correct??

Comment: The gateway IP is wrong.

Comment: @MichaelHampton i installed openvz on this server and vm's working good with this ip and gateway.i think there is a problem on my bridge so gateway is unreachable...

Comment: br0 has a public ip, I think you need to use virbr0 that uses subnet 192.168.122.0 and gateway 192.168.122.1, In this the vm are localy to your server and later if you want to expose an vm service, you can use iptables

Comment: @c4f4t0r guest interface added.its target is vnet0 by default...

Comment: yes, but vnet0 is the virtual ethernet for guest and need to inside the virbr0 bride, unless you want put the guest in br0(public interface), use brctl show

Comment: @c4f4t0r `brctl show` added to post.it show br0 connected to eth0(physical port)

Comment: @c4f4t0r i changed vm interface to virbr0 and added ip in internal range but nothing changed.i must add extra ips to server first!? now only the main ip assigned to the server and extra ips dont added to physical network interface (eth0) yet!!..